# PHP CLI ODBC Using Old Connection

Tags: php, odbc, command-line-interface

Recently, I updated two ODBC datasources in my odbc.ini file to point to a different IP address.  This change works great from the Web pages.  However, anything in PHP run on the command line still connects to the old data source. It's almost as if PHP CLI is caching the old data source.  I am completely stumped.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: if it required changes to the php.ini file, there may be a different one `php-cli.ini` for the CLI.

Comment: It did not require any changes to the php.ini.  I did look in the php-cli.ini and didn't see anything that would cause this problem.

Comment: `PHP CLI is caching` I don't think there would be any caching of the config, in fact the CLI tends to be more dynamic as it doesn't live inside of Apache.

Comment: Yeah, I was grasping at straws trying to figure it out.  Caching was the only thing I could think of!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to my problem but I did find a way to make it behave properly.  I was using the PHP odbc calls (odbc_connect, etc).  I decided to try PDO and it connected to the correct data source.  A much preferred method of connecting anyway!